# Is there an official web browser for on-premises SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, administration, sharepoint-on-prem, browser-compatibility

Is there an official browser for SharePoint on-premises 2013? Where most of the options and features will work? Or there is not such an info? For example if I want to use the "Open with Explorer" option inside our document libraries, then I can only achieve this using IE-11.

Answer (score 4):

their is no dedicated browser for the SharePoint rather they call it supported. As per my experience best browser is always IE.

If you follow this Official documentation they mentioned **Microsoft Edge, Internet Explorer 11, Internet Explorer 10, Internet Explorer 9, Internet Explorer 8** but with certain limitation with IE 11 in Edge Mode as well as Edge browser required Dec 2015 CU for SharePoint.

[Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/browser-support-planning)

Comment: ok thanks for the useful reply and info.. but for example one of the useful options inside sharepoint document libraries is the ability to open the sharepoint documents within your PC using "Open with Explorer" and seems those options will only work with IE-11 ,, as it will not work with Edge or chrome... so instead of saying if there is an official browser for SP-2013,, can we say that IE (10 and 11) is the best browser suited for SP 2013??

Comment: Yes, you are right in saying that. I read that somewhere "ie 11" will give you best experience.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you will find any browser that works best because from my experience each browser has some shortcomings when it comes to SharePoint.

If you try "Open with Explorer" in Edge it won't work there as well.

You can't force browsers to support features that aren't available. There are a lot of things that are reliant on ActiveX controls rather than plain browser compatibility.

**According to me the best would be to use Chrome , feature wise it works best. 
Like there will be problems activating and disabling features in IE but not in Chrome.**

For some things that Chrome cannot do (like open with explorer) unfortunately you will have to reply on IE.

See the Plan browser support in SharePoint 2013 TechNet article.

**https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263526.aspx**

Comment: ok thanks for the useful reply and info, but based on my experience that IE-11 is the best for SP-2013.. as i can not do any thing with chrome that i can not do with IE-11.. while there are some options that will only work with IE-11 for example the "Open with Explorer" .. so not sure why you said that `According to me the best would be to use Chrome ` ?? can you give some reasons?

Comment: Technically , technically yes , On paper IE will always be the best but there are some things that makes me prefer Chrome over IE . Chrome browser works much much faster as compared to IE for opening the pages .SharePoint hosted App uses client based technologies such as JavaScript, CSS and html 5. Chrome engine V8 has some advanced features,all the necessary features are enabled by default .IE and Edge browsers are used widely to access the on premise SharePoint site .Security and other polices are enforced on IE and Edge browser when its accessed in secured network. So user feels slowness .

Answer (score 2):

Like others have pointed out there is no great browser experience for SharePoint On-Prem but IE unfortunately is the best with the most OOB functionality.

You can also use chrome and use a chrome extension called **IE Tab** which can add a lot of the functions you lose when using Chrome vs IE. It does tend to be finicky every once in awhile but from its description: "Display web pages using IE within Chrome. Use Java, Silverlight, ActiveX, Sharepoint, and more. A "Top 10" extension since 2009!".

If you use IE Tab you can set it up to just use IE settings and options on just your SP site and subsites this way it doesnt convert all websites in Chrome to act like IE.

ETA: IE Tab allows you to use the 'Open with Explorer' option as well as every other option that I have tested with it so this is a decent alternative to IE11.

Answer (score 2):

The best browser choice really depends on the work that you want to achieve in SharePoint. 
I am a developer and I know that Chrome works best , especially when you are trying to debug your JavaScript codes . 
Internet explorer is really good if you want to play around with OOTB features , configure web parts but again asy friend mentioned pages will load really slow .