# What is the next best browser to use for Sharepoint 2013 On Prem (now that IE is no longer being supported by MS)?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-on-prem, browser-compatibility, browsers

Simple question - which browser is best for SP 2013, now that IE is no longer being supported by Microsoft?

I know there is some loss in functionality e.g. **Open with Explorer** when using Edge or Chrome. What else will we lose if we switch to Microsoft's preference, Edge?

See the 2nd link below under research - Sharepoint Elder lists lots of issues when using Sharepoint *Online* with Edge, will these same problems occur with SP 2013-Edge?

### Research / Background

- [Is there an official web browser for on-premises SharePoint 2013?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/269763/is-there-an-official-web-browser-for-on-premises-sharepoint-2013/269766#269766)  (*really relevant question  here , but dates from 2019 so we need an update)*
- [What is the best browser to use with SharePoint Online/O365?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294187/what-is-the-best-browser-to-use-with-sharepoint-online-o365)  (*this is a question I'd posted in the same vein, but for SP Online...  I'm left wondering if many of the same issues listed by @Sharepoint Elder will occur on Sharepoint 2013 On Prem too*

Answer (score 2):

We could enable and **use IE Mode in Microsoft Edge** to make the open with explorer works again.

Try following steps to enable it:

1. Open Microsoft Edge.
2. Click the Settings and More (ellipsis) button on the top-right
   corner.
3. Select the Settings option.
4. Click on Default browser.
5. Under the “Internet Explorer compatibility” section, turn on the
   “Allow sites to be reloaded in Internet Explorer mode” toggle
   switch.
   [image]
6. Click the Restart button.
7. After that, we can open site with IE Mode on Edge via reloading a
   page with the compatibility mode manually:

   [image]
8. Now the view in file explorer option is available:

[image]

For similar issue, please refer to:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/520044/how-will-the-open-with-explorer-function-be-replac.html